# Fetching data from Wikipedia using Xpath Query function in Google Sheets ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, xpathquery

What would be the correct Xpath query to use to fetch data from Wikipedia into Google Sheets?

Here is an example I would like to test this with:

Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Angry_Men_(1957_film)

Data to pull: the "running time" value of "96 minutes" located in the right hand side table

Method: using the Google Sheets ImportXML function

I've tried the following, but it returns N/A:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Angry_Men_(1957_film)", "//div[normalize-space() = 'Running time']/following-sibling::td")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your XPath.

The `following-sibling` axis won't work on the markup of that page because the `td` following the 'Running time' `div` is a sibling of its parent `th`. Instead, use the `following` axis with a node type selector: `following::td`. However, that still returns all `td` nodes after the selected `div`, so additionally we need a predicate to select only the first node: `[1]`.

Complete function with XPath:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12_Angry_Men_%281957_film%29", "//div[normalize-space()='Running time']/following::td[1]")
```